# Регулярное выражение PCRE в Python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Я написал регулярное выражение на PCRE:

```
(\`|qx\[|qx\{).*(\`|\]|\})
```

Оно должно парсить строку внутри обратных кавычек (или указанных альтернатив). На Python 2.7 отрабатывает не так, как хотелось бы.

```
expression = re.compile('''(\`|qx\[|qx\{).+(\`|\]|\})''')
result = expression.findall('`   12  $`')
```

Вместо искомой строки получаю:

```
[('`', '`')]
```

Почему так происходит?

Comment: Пример бы привели: что есть, что получаете и что ожидали получить?

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы это выражение матчило 'text', qx[text], qx{text}, а также qx[text' и qx{text], я правильно вас понял? (поменял апострофы на одинарные кавычки, чтобы форматирование не съело)

Comment: Да, но варианты типа qx[text' не обязательны . И кавычка должна быть обратной.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос участок кода, который у вас не работает. Регулярка верная, если вам не нужно, чтобы не матчилась строка qx[text} .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"(`[^`\[\]{}]+`|qx\[[^`\[\]{}]+\]|qx\{[^`\[\]{}]+\})")
print pattern.findall(" `text`, qx[text], qx{text}, а также qx[text` и qx{text]")
```

Вернет

```
['`text`', 'qx[text]', 'qx{text}']
```

Внутри ограничителей не пропускает символы: апостроф, `[`, `]`, `{`, `}`.

В вашем же варианте достаточно сделать группы без обратной связи

```
import re
expression = re.compile('''(?:\`|qx\[|qx\{).+(?:\`|\]|\})''')
print expression.findall('`   12  $`')
```

Результат

```
['`   12  $`']
```

Answer (score 2):

Обратитесь к официальной документации: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall (для версии 2.7 метод ведет себя так же)

Там написано: `If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group.` Т.е., если в выражении присутствуют группы, findall() вернет список групп, что он и делает в вашем случае. Используйте search() или match(), например

```
>>> result = expression.search('`   12  $`')
>>> result.group(0)
'`   12  $`'
>>> result.group(1)
'`'
>>> result.group(2)
'`'
```

Также, используйте r перед строкой с выражением, чтобы избежать возможной обработки Python, чтобы строка осталась 'как есть'.

```
r'(\`|qx\[|qx\{).+(\`|\]|\})'
```